# Plots of trigonometric functions

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I need to do a plot of this function c(t) = (e^(-10t^2))*cos(2pi50t) * (u(t + 3) - u(t - 3)). I don't understand how I can do it. I've already defined the variables of the trigonometric function but I don't know what I have to do with the other function.
This is what I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t= np.arange(0,0.5,0.001)
A= np.exp(-10*(t**2))
f=50

c1 = A * np.cos(2 * np.pi * f * t)
c2 = (u(t+3)-u(t-3))
```

Comment: Line 3 time is used but its defined later. Is there anything before that?
Similarly is e exponent in that case we may need to use np.exp()

Comment: You didn't define `e` - and anyway, the right way is to use [the exponential function](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html)

Comment: I added c = c1 * c2 after defining c2. Where do I define t?

Comment: Do define the variable `u` is it a scalar?

Comment: There are several errors in this question; (1) `t`is defined after A, change the order, (2) `exp**(` is wrong, it has to be `exp(`, (3) `u`is never defined! Check this errors and edit your question.

Comment: @MartaMonteiro what is `u` here, you have to initiate it as well!

Comment: the only problem is that I don't have information about what 'u' is @m.i.cosacak

Comment: Well, WE certainly don't know what it is.

Comment: Looks like `u` is the unit step function.

Comment: I'll have a look! Thanks @swag2198

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `u` is the identity function (returns the input as is), this is the code you need to plot the function. I have used your variable definition and used `t` as an input to the function for flexibility:

```
def u(x):
    return x

def function_c(t):
    A= np.exp(-10*(t**2))
    f=50

    c1 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * f * t)
    c2 = (u(t+3) - u(t-3))
    return A * c1 * c2

t= np.arange(0,0.5,0.001)
plt.plot(t, function_c(t))
```

[image: Plot using the code above]

Of course, if you ever learn the definition of `u`, you can update the definition of `u(x)` and recalculate your plot.

Answer (score 0):

If `u` (which is currently undefined in your code) is a constant, then you just need something like the following:

```
import numpy as np

t = np.arange(0,0.5,0.001)

A= np.exp(-10*(t**2))
f=50
u=1

c1 = A * np.cos(2 * np.pi * f * t)
c2 = (u*(t+3)-u*(t-3))

ct = c1 * c2

myplot = plt.plot(t, ct)
```

However, I assume that `u` is in fact a function.  In which case you need to first define what `u` is.
You could do this my expanding the `c2` term, or you could define a python function `u(t)` which takes in a numpy array `t` and returns an array of the same size which has been modified appropriately.
You can then use this function, passing in `t+3` and `t-3`, for form `c2`.

Using a python function to represent a mathematical function is a much cleaner way to work with numbers in python.  Your code might look something like this after some refactoring:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def u(x):
    # do something to the input array 'x' here
    return x

def c(x):
    f=50
    A = np.exp(-10*(x**2))
    c1 = A * np.cos(2 * np.pi * f * x)
    c2 = (u(x+3)-u(x-3))
    return c1 * c2    

t = np.arange(0,0.5,0.001)

myplot = plt.plot(t, c(t))
```